# AVAudioPlayer..its playing old one

Tags: iphone, objective-c, avaudioplayer

m making an app which requires to play recorded audio files. 
For that m having a sound.h/.m file and setting.h/.m file
In sound I have a method - update player which will update my audio-player if a new recorded files has been created.as follows..

```
-(AVAudioPlayer *)updatePlayer
{
  if (!mAudioPlayer) 
  {
    self.mAudioPlayer = [[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:mURLObj error:nil]autorelease];
  }
    return mAudioPlayer;
}
```

Now , mcalling this metod every time when a new recorded audio file is created in settingcontroller..as follows..

```
-(void)hasNewRecorded:(BOOL)inFlag
{
    if (inFlag == YES)
    {
        mRecorder.mAudioPlayer = [[mRecorder updatePlayer]retain];
    }
    [mRecorder.mAudioPlayer release];
}
```

I know that m doing wrong somewhere..But couldnot able to fix the problem for last 2 days. I'm looking forward for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initiating a new audio player only if doesn't exists here,

```
if (!mAudioPlayer) 
  {
    self.mAudioPlayer = [[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:mURLObj error:nil]autorelease];
  }
```

A new player wont be allocated as a player exists already. So the old audio file will keep playing. Try fixing a breakpoint inside this for loop and check, If that's the problem change the condition - release the old audio player and allocate new one.

Comment: Yes, that I know, but whenever I try to release  the old one then no player is played. Why so...before allocating this , i make that to nil as...  self.mAudioPlayer = nil                                    if (!mAudioPlayer) 
  {
    self.mAudioPlayer = [[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:mURLObj error:nil]autorelease];
  } IS this a wrong way??

Comment: Yes it is. You are making that value as nil and checking whether it is nil to execute a conditional code which obviously won't get executed. Do you see the problem here.